# jQuery Infinite Page Scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to accomplish a ajax content load on page scroll and getting stuck at some parts.

Here is my PHP code:

```
//Fetch Total Record
$objDB = new DB;
$fetchCount = $objDB
   ->setStoredProc( 'petContestFetchImagesCount' )
   ->execStoredProc()
   ->parseXML();
 $fetchCount = $fetchCount->data;

 //Total number of results
 $totalResults = $fetchCount->totalRecords; 

 //Records per page
 $limit = 5; 

 //Total number of pages / calls we will make based on the results
 $pages = ceil($totalResults/$limit);

//What page are we currently on?
$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array(
        'default'   => 1,
        'min_range' => 1,
    ),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total); 

$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<nav id="page_nav"><a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '"></a></nav>' : '';

//Fetch Entries
$objDB = new DB;
$submissions = $objDB
   ->setStoredProc( 'petContestFetchImages' )
   ->setParam("offset", $offset )
   ->setParam("rows", $limit )
   ->execStoredProc()
   ->parseXML();
```

From this point, It knows the number of posts it needs, creates the pagination etc.

I now use an infinateScroll plugin and set it up like so:

```
    var $container = $('[name=posts]')

    $($container).isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 10

    }
})

    $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '#page_nav',
    nextSelector: '#page_nav a',
    itemSelector: '.item',
    pixelsFromNavToBottom: -Math.round($(window).height() * 0.9),
    bufferPx: Math.round($(window).height() * 0.9),
    loading: {
        msgText: $container.attr("data-loading-message"),
        finishedMsg: $container.attr("data-no-more-translators")
        }
}, function(newElements) {
    $container.isotope('appended', $(newElements))
    })

})
```

As I scroll down the page, it is loading the content fine. However, it gets to the last record and keeps loading only the last record every time. If I scroll up and then down again, it loads just the last record.

I tested my stored procedure and its not even outputting results when I say start at record 11 (the last result) and give me 5 more, it returns no data.

Not sure what I am missing here but it shouldnt load any more records after hitting the last one.

I used this for reference:
http://blog.lingohub.com/developers/2013/09/endless-pages-scrolling-masonry/

EDIT:

This client side change works however it doesnt prevent the ajax call from firing, just from appending any results that it does fine.

```
var tmp = 1;
var pages = '<?php echo $pages; ?>

$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '#page_nav',
    nextSelector: '#page_nav a',
    itemSelector: '.item',
    pixelsFromNavToBottom: -Math.round($(window).height() * 0.9),
    bufferPx: Math.round($(window).height() * 0.9),
    loading: {
        msgText: $container.attr("data-loading-message"),
        finishedMsg: $container.attr("data-no-more-translators")
        }
}, function(newElements) {
    if(tmp < pages){
        $container.isotope('appended', $(newElements))
    }
    tmp++;
    })

})
```

Comment: I think that workaround is the best you're gonna get.  Cause according to the plugin documentation.  "Currently there is no way to cancel or opt-out of the behavior".  Maybe just put an alert('You've reached the end') so the user has some sort of feedback, or create a div that you $('#yourdiv').show() if (tmp!<pages)

Comment: Well I appreciate your help! I may have to look into another method of accomplishing this or another plugin for that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you would just do a check to see if you've reached the max page count?

```
  if($page<$pages){
       //Fetch Entries
       $objDB = new DB;
       $submissions = $objDB
        ->setStoredProc( 'petContestFetchImages' )
        ->setParam("offset", $offset )
        ->setParam("rows", $limit )
        ->execStoredProc()
        ->parseXML(); 
    }
```

Then change the nextlink to echo one extra link higher than $pages variable.  Like so...

```
    $nextlink = ($page <= $pages) ? '<nav id="page_nav"><a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '"></a></nav>' : '';
```

Comment: This kinda worked, stopped showing the same record each time however it now doesn't show the last record at all. I have 11 records with 5 per page that come in. So thats a total of 3 pages. It loads 3 pages but the last page doesnt have any content on it because this Database call is never executed to pull the content

Comment: hmm....well if you put ($page<=$pages) it will probably end up doing the same thing it did before.  So you may have to do some sort of client side check.  Where you store the count/pages and then when you scroll you increment it, and check.  Or something along those lines

Comment: Yeah, I tried the <= to see and it kept doing the same thing. I will give that a try!

Comment: Try my edit :)  That might do it.  Just echo one extra link higher than $pages with $nextlink = ($page<=$pages)

Comment: Weird, same issue! I see what your thought was on it. It makes the page 3 ajax call but it doesnt load the content in there. It's always loading `index.php` but it adds the page number on it so i think it hits `index.php?page=3` and then because `if($page<$pages){` isnt true, it doesnt pull the page 3 content

Comment: ah right.  So it needs to be stopped from actually executing the ajax.  So that will definintely be client side check, to prevent the plugin from firing. Not exactly sure how you would do it, as Ive never used that plugin before.  Maybe theres something in the documentation for it?  Although I just checked the InfiniteScroll site, and saw this as a list under disadvantages... "Currently there is no way to cancel or opt-out of the behavior"  "You should display some sort of 'no content available'" when reaching the end

Comment: Yeah, I added to the original question; not sure hot to prevent it from doing an ajax call though